# User Controls Asp .Net

Tags: asp.net, web-user-controls

Task – develop user control, which has <%#Bind(“expression”)%>`

How send parametrs into user control and how to use Bind and Eval ?

Comment: Sounds like you're asking us to do your homework for you... tisk tisk.

Comment: I try learn Asp, maybe this task is very easy for you, but I dont know how do it, better you will recomend some tutorial, sample  etc.

Comment: Do a web search for "ASP.NET data binding" you will find TONS of tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good tutorial about creating user controls and setting their properties in [this MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Basically, you create an ascx page and its code-behind.  In the code-behind, you create the properties that you want exposed and store their values using ViewState.  It is important for your property backing store to be viewstate for reasons discussed [in this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx):

```
public partial class MyControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public DateTime BeginDate 
    {
        get { return (DateTime)(ViewState["BeginDate"] ?? new DateTime()); }
        set { ViewState["BeginDate"] = value; }
    }
    ......
```

The after you register this new user control in your web.config file, you can declarative place an instance of the control in your hosting page and set its property:

```
<Custom:MyControl Id="Mycontrol" runat="server" BeginDate ="2012-01-26" />
```

If you want to use databinding to set the value of the control, simply assign the value of the property to a databinding expression:

```
<Custom:MyControl Id="Mycontrol" runat="server" BeginDate ='<%# GetBeginDate() %>' />
```

Where GetBeginDate() is a public or protected method in your code behind page that returns a date.

You can [see this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860) for a good description of the basics of databinding.